# Populate 2D array with range of random integers, but keep a fixed number of X elements always the same

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I generate random unique integers from 0 to 90:

```
public static int randomNumber() {
    int min = 0;
    int max = 90;
    return min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
}
```

... and use those generated integers to populate a multidimensional 3*5 array:

```
int rows = 3;
int columns = 5;
int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];

public static void populateArray(int[][] array, int rows, int columns) {
    for (int indexRow = 0; indexRow < rows; indexRow++) {
        for (int indexColumn = 0; indexColumn < columns; indexColumn++) {
            array[indexRow][indexColumn] = randomNumber();
        }
    }
}
```

... and this generates something like this:

```
56  64  22  38  78  
73  18  69  39  70  
49  24  3   49  25
```

However, I would like a **fixed number** of, say, 5 **random elements** in the array (no more, no less than 5 random elements) to be always 0, like this:

```
0   64  22  38  0   
73  18  0   39  70  
0   24  3   0   25
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: `ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(0, rows * columns).distinct().limit(5).forEach(i -> array[i / rows][i % rows] = 0);`

Answer (score 1):

You can first evaluate random positions where your matrix would have zeros:

```java
static int[] zeroPositions(int totalPositions, int zeroPositions){
    int[] result = new int[zeroPositions];
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < zeroPositions; i++){
        int currentPosition = random.nextInt(totalPositions);
        while (contains(result, currentPosition)){
            currentPosition = (currentPosition + 1) % totalPositions;
        }
        result[i] = currentPosition;
    }
    return result;
}
```

At the above code I omit some checks like that zero positions to be not greater than total positions (to save space).

Another what you need here and a bit later is a method that checks if an array contains a value:

```java
public static boolean contains(int[] source, int value){
    for(int i = 0; i < source.length; i++){
        if(source[i] == value){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now you should amend your `randomNumber` method in order to have minim as `1` since zeroes would be just not filled cells.

```java
public static int randomNumber() {
    int min = 1; // skip 0
    int max = 90;
    return min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
}
```

And amend `populateArray` method to test if a current position has to hold zero:

```java
public static void populateArray(int[][] array, int rows, int columns, int[] zeroPositions) {

    for (int indexRow = 0; indexRow < rows; indexRow++) {
        for (int indexColumn = 0; indexColumn < columns; indexColumn++) {
            if(!contains(zeroPositions, indexRow * columns + indexColumn)){
                array[indexRow][indexColumn] = randomNumber();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's run everything:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 5;
    int[][] matrix = new int[rows][cols];
    populateArray(matrix, rows, cols, zeroPositions(rows * cols, 5));
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

And finally some outputs:

```
8 58 0 0 28 
39 79 54 0 0 
28 0 30 51 56 

65 81 27 0 0 
17 21 74 0 0 
0 16 47 69 80 

44 0 18 57 30 
0 0 37 76 61 
0 0 38 77 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I went a little overboard to make it more general.

```
int[][] result = create(3,5,5,90);
for (int[] r : result) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
}
```

prints

```
[0, 48, 0, 0, 41]
[0, 32, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 81, 25]
```

- first check the invariant to ensure the count is <= row * cols
- create an array of 0's to fill result array
- then generate an array of indices into the result array
- Then fill result array by randomly selecting and index and the new
  number to be stored.
- adjust the indices array to not repeat the previous index.
- return the result.

```
// rows, cols - the array dimensions
// count - is the number of randoms numbers and the 
// max - is the max size of that number.    
public static int[][] create(int rows, int cols, int count, int max) {
    int size = rows * cols;
    if (count > size) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Size and count don't match");
    }
    Random r = new Random();
    // an array of zeroes
    int[][] result = new int[rows][cols];
    // an array of indices into result
    int[] indices = new int[size];
    Arrays.setAll(indices, i->i++);
    // now loop thru filling in result array without
    // repeating any index.
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int pos = r.nextInt(size);
        result[indices[pos]/cols][indices[pos]%cols] = r.nextInt(max)+1;
        indices[pos] = indices[--size];
    }
    return result;
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void populateArray(int[][] array, int fixedNumber, int fixedNumberCount) {
    int rows = array.length, cols = array[0].length, size = rows * cols;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fixedNumberCount; ++i)
        list.add(fixedNumber);
    for (int i = fixedNumberCount; i < size;) {
        int r = randomNumber();
        if (r == fixedNumber) continue;
        list.add(r);
        ++i;
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    for (int r = 0, i = 0; r < rows; ++r)
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c, ++i)
            array[r][c] = list.get(i);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = new int[5][5];
    populateArray(array, 0, 5);
    for (int[] row : array)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

output:

```
[9, 71, 57, 86, 70]
[0, 0, 17, 70, 22]
[21, 0, 72, 7, 83]
[18, 37, 45, 8, 10]
[42, 8, 0, 85, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
public class RandomNumber{
static int[] createUniqueRandomNumber(int from,int to)
{
 int n=to-from+1;
 int a[] =new int[n];
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
  a[i]=i;
 }
 int[] result =new int[n];
  int x=n;
 SecureRandom rd=new SecureRandom();
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
   int k=rd.nextInt(x);
    a[k] =a[x-1];
    x--
  }
  return result;
  }
 }
 public static void main(Strin[] args)
  {
   int[] result =createUniqueRandomNumber(4,15);
    for(int i=0;i<resuly.length;i++)
     {
       System.out.println(result[i] + " ");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).